# Formatting results across multiple columns from MySQL database with PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am looking for a way to display data from a MySQL database across multiple columns in a similar fashion to a spreadsheet.

I have not started the table design as yet as I am unsure of the best approach to achieve what I would like.

I have considered the following:

```
TABLE 1 - Homework Task

id (INT)

task (VARCHAR)
```

This table is just a list of homework tasks

```
TABLE 2 - Students

id (INT)

studentName (VARCHAR)
```

This is just a list of students

```
TABLE 3 - Homework Grades

id (INT)

homeworkTaskId (INT)

studentId (INT)

grade (VARCHAR)

percentage (DECIMAL)
```

This will hold the marks for each homework task for each student

Now, what I would like to achieve is to be able to display the data like this:

[image]

What I am struggling with is my knowledge of SQL commands and knowing if it is possible to retrieve the data in such a way that I can loop through it to display in this format?

I am using PHP with a PDO connection to the MySQL database.

Many thanks in advance for any possible assistance in this matter.

Comment: I am unsure what to try as I don't know how to set up the loop.

Comment: try, jQgrid.  http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:groupingheadar  - This is a display issue and should not really affect how the data is retrieved.

Comment: As for pulling the data out, just use 1 query to pull out the students, and additional queries to pull out the homework.

Comment: I now how to format the HTML and get the groupings but I don't know how to loop through the data to retrieve it.

Comment: It's easy to retrieve the first column and display the Homework 1 results for each student...BUT, I don't know how to set up the loop(s) to show results for Homework 2, Homework 3 etc

Comment: Pull out the students with one query, loop through and pull out their homework ( inside the loop ) with a second query.  Using a foreign key  ( student.id ) to look up the records in Homework should be fast.  Simple

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I am sure it is simple when you know how.  However, I am a beginner and struggling with this one.  I understand what you are saying about the loop and the second query BUT I have to display the data in the relevant column.  For example, if JOHN SMITH is absent for the first homework and then only completes the second and third homework he will only have 2 entries in the database.  When I loop through then his data will be placed into the first 2 sets of columns rather than set 2 and 3.

Comment: @Newbeginnings - I posted an example as an answer.

Comment: Is the number of homework "tasks" variable per student, or will they all have say 5 homework records?   If they are variable then it will be more difficult.  For example one student has 4 homework records, another has 8 and another has none...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use 2 queries, it's much simpler and if your looking it up by the foreign key ( student.id ) in the homework table, it should be fast enough where performance wont be an issue.

```
   $DB = new PDO('mysql:host='.$conf['dbhost'].';dbname='.$conf['dbname'], $conf['dbuser'], $conf['dbpass']);

   $students_stmt =  $DB->query('SELECT * FROM students');

   $homework_stmt = $DB->prepare('
       SELECT
            h.id, h.grade, h.percentage, ht.task 
       FROM
            homework AS h
       JOIN
            homework_task AS ht
       ON
          ht.id = t.homeworkTaskId
       WHERE
           h.studentId = :student_id
   ');


   $data = [];

   $max_homework = 0; //maximum number of homework records

   while( false !== ( $student = $students_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) )){

       $homework_stmt->execute([':studentId'=>$student['id']]);

       $i = 1;
       while( false !== ( $homework = $homework_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) )){
          $student["homework_$i"] = $homework;
          ++$i;
       }
       if( $i > $max_homework )  $max_homework = $i;

       $data[] = $student;
   }
```

You'll wind up with an array like this

```
 $data = [ 0 =>   //first student
     [
        'studentName' => 'Some Guy',
        'homework_1' => [
            'grade' => 'A',
            'percentage' => '92'
        ],
        'homework_2' => [
            'grade' => 'B',
            'percentage' => '85'
        ]
        'homework_3' => [ .... ]
     ], 1 => [ ... //second student ]
  ];
```

Then you can loop over `$data` and create the table

The `$max_homework` is because when you go to display it you will need to know how many homework columns you need ( [group, percentage] ) that way you can create the proper number of headers in your table and fill the students that have less then that.  So each row in the table has the same number of cells, if that makes sense.  That is if the number of homework records vary from student to student.

By the way this code is untested as I have no way to know the full schema of your tables. It's just an example of the simplest approach ( using PDO ).

Comment: Thanks...it's heading in the direction I was thinking.  The Homework Task table actually contains a lot of other data as well...hence the need for the third table.

Comment: Then you will need to join on it in the second query.  Added in an example of how to join them.

Comment: If the number of homework records is variable then you will have to know the student with the most number of homework so you can fill the lesser ones with empty data.  When you display them they will need the same number of homework columns ( even if they are just empty )

Comment: @Newbeginnings - I made a couple of "Changes"

Comment: Thanks for all your efforts.  I got it working with a similar loop to yours and with a conditional.

Comment: Cool, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example from the php documentation that should get you started. $row will take on the names of the fields in the database because we chose result->fetchassoc

```
<?
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER by ID";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

/* fetch associative array */
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<div>".$row['studentname']."</div>";
    echo "<div>".$row['studentgrade']."</div>";
}

/* free result set */
$result->free();
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```